# adb devices does not detect android phone on MAC

Tags: android, macos

I am trying to get my android detected on MAC and followed online instruction that were available. Turning on USB mass storage led to MAC detecting it in Finder, but it does not show in list below -

```
adb devices
```

- Device - Micromax A111
- Android - 4.1.2
- USB Debugging - On
- USB storage - It gets automatically switched off once cable is
  unplugged. Turned on while it was connceted.
- adb_usb.ini - added vender number 0x1c9e and did ./adb kill-server
- Installed ADB wifi - But its prerequisite is to have adb recognize
  device once connected with data cable , which is not working and a rooted device
- data cable being used - one that was shipped with device that can
  also be plugged to adapter.
- device - brand new
- mac - 10.7.5
- I also tried to detect device on a ubuntu machine by installing first
  android ADT bundle for linux and there is the same problem

Comment: Have you tried restarting your Android Device?

Comment: I just talked to Micromax customer care and they say that even though option is there to enable USB Debugging mode, that is only for developers in company and not intended to be used by public. I thought USB debugging mode was generic thing common across all Android phones,, but looks its not so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me now using google chrome's chrome://inspect/#devices
Device gets discovered